# Adding List Elements to a Dictionary

Tags: printing, dictionary, syntax-error, python-2.x, counting

I am trying to take a list of words that I have imported from a textfile and make a dictionary , where the value is incremented each time the word is passed over in the loop. However, with the current code I have, none are added and only the value I add initiall is there when I print the dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pymysql
from os import path
import re
db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='db_cc')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id, needsprocessing, SchoolID, ClassID, TaskID FROM sharedata WHERE needsprocessing = 1")
r = cursor.fetchall()
print(r)
from os import path
import re
noentities = len(r)
a = r[0][1]
b = r[0][2]
c = r[0][3]
d = r[0][4]
filepath = "/codecompare/%s/%s/%s/%s.txt" %(a, b, c, d)
print(filepath)
foo = open(filepath, "r")
steve = foo.read()
rawimport = steve.split(' ')
dictionary = {"for":0}
foo.close()
for word in rawimport:
    if word in dictionary:
        dictionary[word] +=1
    else:
        dictionary[word] = 1
print dictionary
```

Some rawimport values are as follows:

```
print rawimport
['Someting', 'something', 'dangerzones', 'omething', 'ghg', 'sdf', 'hgiinsfg', '932wrtioarsjg', 'fghbyghgyug', 'sadiiilglj']
```

Additionally, when trying to print from the code, it throws

```
... print dictionary
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print dictionary
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, if I run print dictionary by itself it prints:

```
{'for': 0}
```

Which is evidence that for loop did nothing.

Any ideas?
Running Python 2.7.2

edit: updated to reflect closing of file and to make loop simpler
edit: added sample rawimport data

Comment: In your for loop, why don't you do `else: dictionary[word] = 1` instead of assigning 0 then adding 1?
Could you show an example of the content of rawimport.
You didn't close foo.

Comment: I have closed foo, changed to the line you gave and the issue still arises. I will add examples of rawimport in the question. Thanks for your help, Tom

Answer (score 0):

I received the same Traceback when working through this in the Python interpreter -- it arose from not leaving the context of the for loop:

```
>>> for word in rawimport:
...     if word in dictionary:
...             dictionary[word]+=1
...     else:
...             dictionary[word]=1
... print dictionary
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    print dictionary
        ^
```

The interpreter thinks your print statement belongs to the for loop, and errors because it's not appropriately indented. (If you did indent it, of course, it would print the dictionary during each pass). The solution to that (assuming you're doing this in the interpreter, which was how I reproduced your error) is hitting enter again:

```
>>> for word in rawimport:
...     if word in dictionary:
...             dictionary[word]+=1
...     else:
...             dictionary[word]=1
... 
>>> print dictionary
{'for': 1, 'fghbyghgyug': 1, '932wrtioarsjg': 1, 'dangerzones': 1, 'sdf': 1, 'ghg': 1, 'Someting': 1, 'something': 1, 'omething': 1, 'sadiiilglj': 1, 'hgiinsfg': 1}
'''
```